# PowerShell to extract specific column from csv and store in a variable

Tags: powershell

My keys.csv file looks like this

```
 PrjKey BldKey      key
 LS     LOOKUPSNAP1 LS-LOOKUPSNAP1
 LS     LSUH3       LS-LSUH3
 LSPERF LPMDS0      LSPERF-LPMDS0
 LSPERF LSP0        LSPERF-LSP0
```

I want to extract the values column "key" and store in a variable. I tried this

```
 Import-Csv .\keys.csv  | select key | ft -hide
```

the output has a blank line at the top. How can I eliminate it. I only want those 4 values to be "stored in a variable" Yes I don't want to save the output as a csv again.

Can someone help please?

Comment: `$keys = Import-Csv .\keys.csv  | select -ExpandProperty key` ? Don't use `Format-` for storing/manipulating data they are purely for console output and information _display_

Comment: Ah I thought its good for storing as well. Thank you!  -ExpandProperty works good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You had the right idea of using `Select-Object` to get the one property you want. The two issues you had was that `Select-Object key` returns and object array with a key property when it looks like you just want string array of keys. Also **never** use `Format-cmdlets` when you want to save the data or use it in another form. They destroy objects for the purpose of display data on the screen. So that all being said..

```
$keys = Import-Csv .\keys.csv | select -ExpandProperty key
```

Depending on your PowerShell version

```
$keys = (Import-Csv .\keys.csv).key
```

Comment: How to pick the specific row value in a column of our choice ?