# Powershell to remove text in CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv

So I have a program that prints out some text, in column 1 and down:

Is it possible to make a powershell script that deletes all the text besides the numbers `100995 1557`? the place where those numbers are, are the only ones I need and want in my Excel file.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why does this have the `ruby` tag if you're not using `ruby`? Also, can you place the actual contents of the file inside the post instead of on `imgur`?

Comment: ohhh sorry im new to stackoverflow. I ment to set "powershell" not ruby

Comment: You're looking for `Import-Csv`. Import the file, expand the values of the field `Value`, and you're done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell to extract specific column from csv and store in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021473/powershell-to-extract-specific-column-from-csv-and-store-in-a-variable)

Comment: @angsarwiechers This is very close to an answer.  I'm tempted to just phrase what you said in the form of a line of PS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
import-csv myfile.csv | Select Value| export-csv newfile.csv
```

(This is just Angsar Wiecher's comment, expressed in PS)